# While loop doesn't stop (PHP)

Tags: php, loops

I want to make statistics by day, month, years, for my website

so first I checked if the database is empty if that correct I insert today date with 1 in the count

but for example if I have the last day in database is 2016-03-28 I need to add to 2016-03-31 and 2016-04-01 ..... 2016-04-30 ... etc to today's date.

I make it but I have a problem the while loop doesn't stop sow it's work but when he went to today's date it's doesn't stop

```
<?php
while($rows['st_date'] != $date1 ){
    if($rows['st_date'] != $date1) {
        $akhir = $datedate1 - $date_day;
        $akhir_month = $date3 - $date_month;
        if($akhir_month != 1 && $akhir > 0) {
            $n = $akhir;
            for($j=1; $j<=$n; $j++){
                $date5 = ++$date_day;
                $date6 = $date_month;
                $date7 = $date_years;
                $final_date = $date7.'-'.$date6.'-'.$date5;
                $sql3 = "INSERT INTO statistics (st_date, count) values ('$final_date', '0')";
                mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
            }
        }
        else if ($akhir_month > 1){
            $datemonth1 = ++$date_month;
            $date_day = 1;
            $datefinal = $date_years.'-'.$datemonth1.'-'.$date_day;

            $datedate1 =  date("t",strtotime($datefinal));
            $akhir = $datedate1 - 0;
            $n = $akhir;
            $datetest = $date_month;
            for($j=1; $j<=$n; $j++){
                $date5 = $j;
                $date6 = $datetest;
                $date7 = $date_years;
                $final_date = $date7.'-'.$date6.'-'.$date5;
                $sql3 = "INSERT INTO statistics (st_date, count) values ('$final_date', '0')";
                mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
            }
        }
        else if ($akhir_month == 1) {
            $n = $resm;
            $i = 1;
            for($j=1; $j<=$n; $j++){
                $date5 = ++$i;
                $date6 = $date3;
                $date7 = $date_years;
                $final_date = $date7.'-'.$date6.'-'.$date5;
                $sql3 = "INSERT INTO statistics (st_date, count) values ('$final_date', '0')";
                mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
            }
        }

        $sql3 = "UPDATE statistics SET count = '1' where st_date = '$date1'";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
    }

    else if($rows['st_date'] == $date1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to exit the while when the last date in the database == today date

Comment: Your `while` loop only checks one entry. You are not getting next entry or change its content somehow.

Comment: Where are you advancing the pointer?

Comment: @lolbas this's just a part from my code it has 161 line

Comment: @PeeHaa any pointer ?

Comment: Neither `$rows['st_date']` nor `$date1` ever changes in your loop.

Comment: @Y.Saad your loop condition is not changed within loop scope hence it doesn't matter what's happening outside of it.

Comment: `$rows['st_date']` this variable I take it from the database, so, how I can refresh it ?

Comment: @lolbas if the database doesn't have any rows I add automatically the date of taday but else, I make todaydate - last date in database, if result = 1 I add today if note I make this while to add what I need, the code it's work but I need to exit while when the last date in database == today date

Answer (score 0):

Neither `$date1` nor `$rows['st_date']` ever change in your `while` loop. You are telling the computer to keep going through that loop while `$rows['st_date']` does not equal `$date1`. Given that neither of these two variables will ever change, when the program gets to your `while` loop, that statement will either be true forever (endless loop), or it will be false and skip past the loop.

Somewhere in your while loop, you need to have a line that says something to the effect of:

```
$date1 = "xxxx-xx-xx";
```

or

```
$rows['st_date'] = "xxxx-xx-xx";
```

or

```
$rows['st_date'] = $date1;
```

If you can tell me exactly what you are trying to have it do, I can tell you what code to write. If not, I hope this helps.

On a second point, the `else if` statements will never run because the `if` statement is the same condition as your `while` loop.